# How to put a jar file in memory into classpath when compiling with jdk1.6 compiler API?

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I'm doing some dynamic compilation using jdk1.6 compiler API.
For now, I just dumped all jar files needed to disk , in order to include them in classpath when compiling.
Is there some kind of trick to put jar files in memory into classpath directly?
I failed to figure out how to do this by extending javax.tools.ForwardingJavaFileManager.
Could someone give me some hints?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) on how to add jar files to your class path using manifest.

There should be a `META-INF` folder inside of your jar, the Manifest.mf file should be in that folder of the jar.

There is also an option to put the jar files in `JAVA_HOME/lib/ext` but this is a bad practice. The JRE can be used by many other applications than yours, and they don't need to have your classes in their classpath.

Comment: What does this have to do with putting JAR files **that are in memory** onto the classpath?

Comment: My jar files are in memory. I can obtain their input streams but I don't want to write them onto the disk. So how could I put those memory jar files onto classpath directly?

Comment: You can have a custom class loader load from memory. You can force the system loader, load specified classes from memory. However, you can't change the default system loader to read from memory on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own FileManager which is entirely in memory.  Using this approach to can load and even write results into an in-memory "file system"

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler/blob/master/compiler/src/main/java/net/openhft/compiler/MyJavaFileManager.java

Comment: In fact, I already have almost the same filemanager impl as yours. This could do dynamic java source reading and dynamic class generating all in memory. But, when reading classpath jar files, this filemanager also delegate this action to the StandardJavaFileManager, which could only read classpath jar files on hard disk. So, I still don't know how to include memory jar files onto classpath.